# Warning: Different store and key passwords not supported for PKCS12 KeyStores. Ignoring user-specified -keypass value

Tags: android, android-studio, jks

Android Studio Arctic Fox seems introduced a lot of bugs including creation of Key Store.

[image]

I confirmed that all passwords are correct. There is also an issue when a key store password is different from key password another error is thrown.

```
Warning:  Different store and key passwords not supported for PKCS12 KeyStores. Ignoring user-specified -keypass value.
```

But what we don't understand is before we were able to release and deliver apps where key store password and key password are different and we still use that jks file up today when updating our apps. Is this a part of mandatory update due to overlooking the possibility migration from jks to pkcs12?

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20210326203837/https://developer.android.com/studio/known-issues#ki-key-keystore-warning says to not use different passwords! ...as a workaround. A temporary one?

Comment: Related question - [Warning: Different store and key passwords not supported for PKCS12 KeyStores. Ignoring user-specified -keypass value. in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66621669/1455694)

Answer (score 0):

This might be caused when a symmetric key is stored in the keystore of type PKCS12. You cannot have a password for the key you store in this type of keystore.